# QWidget::visibleRegion() equivalent for QML items

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I would like to know the portion of a QML item that is visible on the screen. For example, if a `Button` is partially covered by a `SplitView`.

[image]

I can achieve this in QtWidgets using the function visibleRegion() but can't seem to find an equivalent function for QML items.

Comment: I don't believe that exists in QML, unfortunately.

Comment: QML items don't implement some painting logic so this functionality is unnecessary.  All the job do a C++ class that behind an QML item. You can easy implement your own class that do that and expose it to QML.